# How to check the radio button based on results in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to check radio button but its not working and below is my code
My template,

```
<form  [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">     
    <label class="control-label">ACCESS SETTINGS</label>

    <input id="radio-2" [formControl]="form.controls['status']" value = 1  type="radio">
    <label >Show to everyone</label>

    <input id="radio-1" [formControl]="form.controls['status']" value = 2   type="radio">
    <label >Show to friends</label>

    <input id="radio-3" [formControl]="form.controls['status']" value = 3  type="radio">
    <label f>Do not show now</label>
</form>
```

My ts,

```
  .subscribe(details1 => {
     this.details1 = details1;
     this.tocheck = this.details1.display;
  });

  this.form = fbld.group({ 
     status: [this.tocheck],     
  });
```

my service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class GetAllList {
    str = localStorage.getItem('social');
    loc = JSON.parse(this.str);
    id =  this.loc._id;
    private _productUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/getprofiledetails/'+this.id;

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> { 
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
           .map((response: Response) => {    
              return  response.json().data;
           });  
    }
}
```

Here i put 2 consoles in which "valuein" is showing result but "valueout" is showing undefined.Here how to declare "tocheck"  a global variable?Can someone help me

Comment: To fully understand your needs please add some more code.. Your Component, the Template, ...

Answer (score 0):

That's cause of your first `console.log` is inside of that subscribe.
This will be executed IF your observable gets the `details1`.

And your second `console.log` is executed BEFORE the details are received..
So you have to change the radio-button's state inside that `subscribe` function!

Comment: mxii,i had done like this but not wrking  .subscribe(
        details1 => {
        this.details1 = details1;
        this.tocheck = this.details1.display;
         this.form = fbld.group({ 
            status: [this.tocheck],
          
        });
        });